# Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Quote__r'

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to run this code, but I am getting that error

> Apex Class

```
public List<sbaa__Approval__c> getApprovalList(){
    List<sbaa__Approval__c> listOfApproval = [SELECT ID, Quote__r.Id, Name, Quote__r.TNV_Payment_Terms__c, 
                                              Quote__r.Name, Quote__r.TNV_Sector__c,
                                              Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Id,
                                              Quote__r.TNV_Effective_Non_Standard_Discount__c,
                                              Quote__r.Owner.Name,
                                              Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Name, Quote__r.SBQQ__SalesRep__c,
                                              Quote__r.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Owner.Name,
                                              Quote__r.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.StageName,
                                              Quote__r.TNV_Requester_Comments__c,
                                              Quote__r.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Name
                                              FROM sbaa__Approval__c 
                                             ];
    return listOfApproval;
}
```

> VFC

```
<apex:component controller="EmailSenderController" access="global">
    <div value="{!ApprovalList}">
        <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="right"
                    style="border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thick; border-right-color: #009EDB;"
                    width="20%">
                    Quote Number
                </td>
                <td width="80%">
                    <!-- <b><a href="https://{!MID($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_130, 9, 28)}/{!relatedTo.Quote__r.Id}">{!relatedTo.Quote__r.Name}</a></b> -->
                    <apex:outputlink value="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140,FIND('.com',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+4)+ApprovalList.Quote__r.Id}">{!ApprovalList.Quote__r.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"
                    style="border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thick; border-right-color: #009EDB;"
                    width="20%">
                    Approval
                </td>
                <td width="80%">
                    <apex:outputlink value="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140,FIND('.com',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+4)+ApprovalList.Id}">{!ApprovalList.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </div>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Quote__r' this is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApprovalList()` is returning a list, so you need to treat it as a list in your Visualforce code:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!ApprovalList}" var="approval">
  <<apex:outputLink value="{! ... approval.Quote__r.Id ... }" />
</apex:repeat>
```

The `...` are meant for brevity. You should be able to use most of the original code verbatim, simply changing `ApprovalList` to `Approval`, as demonstrated above. You can also use any of `apex:panelGrid`, `apex:dataTable`, or `apex:pageBlockTable` for other formatted options.

Comment: Could you me please show me, I dont have much idea about this code